# Shortcut for "build and run" in Eclipse for Mac (OSX)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, shortcut

I'm looking for a shortcut that will allow me to build and run a project in Java that is currently opened.

There is a shortcut like this: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then <kbd>j</kbd> but it only works if there is a `public static void main()` method delacred in the currently viewed file.

Is there a shortcut that can be used no matter which file of the project you want to run is currently opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That key combination will work for the whole project only if the focus/selection is on a project in Package Explorer or Project Explorer.

Alternatively, you can re-launch the last program (or test), regardless of where your focus is, using the **Run Last Launched** command:

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Mac: <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (depending on your settings of the function keys).

That's a reasonable alternative if you find yourself repeatedly running the same program or test.